# Web Scraping School Project

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I need help with a school project. The code that I have "#" I can't seem to get to work with the table I scraped. I need to change it into a data frame. Can anyone see what I'm missing and if I am missing a step.

```
Tertiary=pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tertiary_education_attainment")
Tertiary=pd.DataFrame(Tertiary[1])
#Tertiary=Tertiary.drop(["Non-OECD"], axis=1, inplace=True) 
print(Tertiary.dtypes)
#Tertiary["Age25-64(%)"] = pd.to_numeric(Tertiary["Age25-64(%)"])
#Tertiary["Age"] = pd.to_numeric(Tertiary["Age"])
print(Tertiary.dtypes)
print()
#print(Tertiary.describe)
print()
#print(Tertiary.isnull().sum())
#print(Tertiary)
```

Comment: Thank you. First time using this site and I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: What programming language is this? Please make sure you tag your question with the appropriate language.

Comment: Could you add the output of some of your code's variables? For example, adding the output of `Tertiary.head()` after you first read it in. That way, other users may not need to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine for me.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tertiary_education_attainment")
table = pd.DataFrame(df[1])
print(table)
print(table.columns)
```

Output:

```
           Country Age 25–64 (%)       Age                                Year Non-OECD
           Country Age 25–64 (%) 25–34 (%) 35–44 (%) 45–54 (%) 55–64 (%)  Year Non-OECD
0        Australia            42        48        46        38        33  2014      NaN
1          Austria            30        38        33        27        21  2014      NaN
2          Belgium            37        44        42        34        26  2014      NaN
3           Brazil            14        15        14        14        11  2013      NaN
4           Canada            54        58        61        51        45  2014      NaN
5            Chile            21        27        24        17        14  2013      NaN
6            China            17        27        15         7         2  2018      NaN
7         Colombia            22        28        23        18        16  2014      NaN
8       Costa Rica            18        21        19        17        17  2014      NaN
9   Czech Republic            22        30        21        20        15  2014      NaN
10         Denmark            36        42        41        33        29  2014      NaN
11         Estonia            38        40        39        35        36  2014      NaN
12         Finland            42        40        50        44        34  2014      NaN
13          France            32        44        39        26        20  2013      NaN
14         Germany            27        28        29        26        25  2014      NaN
15          Greece            28        39        27        26        21  2014      NaN
16         Hungary            23        32        25        20        17  2014      NaN
17         Iceland            37        41        42        36        29  2014      NaN
18       Indonesia             8        10         9         8         4  2011      NaN
19         Ireland            41        51        49        34        24  2014      NaN
20          Israel            49        46        53        48        47  2014      NaN
21           Italy            17        24        19        13        12  2014      NaN
22           Japan            48        59        53        47        35  2014      NaN
23          Latvia            30        39        31        27        23  2014      NaN
24       Lithuania            37        53        38        30        28  2014      NaN
25      Luxembourg            46        53        56        40        32  2014      NaN
26          Mexico            19        25        17        16        13  2014      NaN
27     Netherlands            34        44        38        30        27  2014      NaN
28     New Zealand            36        40        41        32        29  2014      NaN
29          Norway            42        49        49        36        32  2014      NaN
30          Poland            27        43        32        18        14  2014      NaN
31        Portugal            22        31        26        17        13  2014      NaN
32          Russia            54        58        55        53        50  2013      NaN
33    Saudi Arabia            22        26        22        18        14  2013      NaN
34        Slovakia            20        30        21        15        14  2014      NaN
35        Slovenia            29        38        35        24        18  2014      NaN
36    South Africa             7         5         7         8         7  2012      NaN
37     South Korea            45        68        56        33        17  2014      NaN
38           Spain            35        41        43        30        21  2014      NaN
39          Sweden            39        46        46        32        30  2014      NaN
40     Switzerland            40        46        45        38        31  2014      NaN
41          Turkey            17        25        16        10        10  2014      NaN
42       Taiwan[3]            45         X         X         X         X  2015      NaN
43  United Kingdom            42        49        46        38        35  2014      NaN
44   United States            44        46        47        43        41  2014      NaN
```

__

```
MultiIndex([(      'Country',       'Country'),
            ('Age 25–64 (%)', 'Age 25–64 (%)'),
            (          'Age',     '25–34 (%)'),
            (          'Age',     '35–44 (%)'),
            (          'Age',     '45–54 (%)'),
            (          'Age',     '55–64 (%)'),
            (         'Year',          'Year'),
            (     'Non-OECD',      'Non-OECD')],
           )
```